# Topology question for denial of statements

Tags: general-topology

[image]

Hello guys, need some help here with Q9. This is a question of topology.
All I can see that is 2nd quantifier (for all x belong to U) flipped to the 3rd place in statement 8. Other than that, is there anything else I am missing?

Also, does this relate to the concept of continuity or Lipschitz continuity? Do i need to explain that although its common in both the statements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $7$ and $8$ look like the condition for continuity and uniform continuity respectively.

Answer (score 2):

The point is that flipping the quantifiers results in a $\delta$ that must work for all $x$, and this is the notion of uniform continuity on $U$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.